# After complete the widget animation run a function in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

In Flutter framework by extending the AnimatedWidget class is implemented a simple animation widget that changes color. How is it possible after complete the widget animation run a function?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can listen on the status of an [`AnimationController`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/animation/AnimationController-class.html):

```
var _controller = new AnimationController(
    0.0, 
    const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
);

_controller.addStatusListener((status) {
  if(status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
    // custom code here
  }
});    

Animation<Offset> _animation = new Tween<Offset>(
  begin: const Offset(100.0, 50.0),
  end: const Offset(200.0, 300.0),
).animate(_controller);
```

Comment: i'm not entirely sure where to put this... initState()? build()?

Comment: `_controller.addStatusListener((status) {

      if(status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
    // Getting control inside this check multiple times.
    //Code here needs to be executed exactly once, only after the entire animation is completed
    // What should be done to achieve this?
  } });`

Comment: What `status` do you get after the first `AnimationStatus.completed`?
You can always add another flag like `if(status == AnimationStatus.completed && !isRunOnce) { isRunOnce = true; }` with `bool isRunOnce = false;` at the top of your widget.

Answer (score 25):

also you can use this :

```
_animationController.forward().whenComplete(() {
 // put here the stuff you wanna do when animation completed!
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simple do:

```dart
_controller.forward().then((value) => {
      //run code when end
});
```

This run the animation forward(you can use `reverse` or any other modes) and call to `//run code when end` when it end.
Acording to official docs, `.forward()`:
`Returns a [TickerFuture] that completes when the animation is complete.`

So using the `then` of the `Future` api over the `TickerFuture` returned in `_controller.forward()` you can execute any code when the animation completed.