# Flutter: Perform an action when a countdown timer reaches 0

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I've created a screen in Flutter that displays a countdown timer.  I'm able to play, pause and restart the timer, but I am trying to figure out how to perform an action when the timer reaches 0 (for example, restart itself).

As the dart file is fairly lengthy, I'm just copying below what I believe to be the relevant portions here. But I can add more if needed.

First I create a widget/class for the countdown timer:

```
class Countdown extends AnimatedWidget {
  Countdown({ Key key, this.animation }) : super(key: key, listenable: animation);
  Animation<int> animation;

  @override

  build(BuildContext context){
    return Text(
      animation.value.toString(),
      style: TextStyle(         
        fontSize: 120,
        color: Colors.deepOrange
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I then have a stateful widget which creates the controller and also imports some data (`gameData.countdownClock` is the countdown timer's start time, it comes from user input at an earlier screen):

```
class _GameScreenState extends State<GameScreen> with TickerProviderStateMixin {

AnimationController _controller;

  _GameScreenState(this.gameData);
  GameData gameData;

  @override


  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(seconds: gameData.countdownClock),
    );
  }
```

And then the container that displays the clock:

```
Container(
                                          child: Countdown(
                                            animation: StepTween(
                                              begin: gameData.countdownClock,
                                              end: 0,
                                            ).animate(_controller),
                                          ),
                                        ),
```

Do I have to add a listener in that last container?  Or somewhere else?  (Or something else entirely!)

Any help is appreciated.  Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer on this page:

[After complete the widget animation run a function in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50473357/after-complete-the-widget-animation-run-a-function-in-flutter)

I needed to add `.addStatusListener` to the animation controller in the `initState()`.

So the new `initState()` code looks like this:

```
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(seconds: gameData.countdownClock),
    );

    _controller.addStatusListener((status){
      if(status == AnimationStatus.completed){
        _controller.reset();
      }
    }
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible value of Animation controller is between 0 to 1.
So I think you have to add listener on `gamedata.countDownClock`
Please check the below code you might get some idea from it.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class GameScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _GameScreenState createState() => _GameScreenState();
}

class _GameScreenState extends State<GameScreen> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  int countdownClock = 10;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // Your Game Data Counter Change every one Second
    const oneSec = const Duration(seconds:1);
    new Timer.periodic(oneSec, (Timer t) {
      // Restart The Counter Logic
      if (countdownClock == 0)
        countdownClock = 11;
      setState(() { countdownClock = countdownClock - 1; });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("")),
      body: Center(
        child: Text('$countdownClock')
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks like a good solution.  For my code I realized the best answer was to add `.addStatusListener` to the controller in `initState()`.